# Export to excel with hyperlinks, merged cells and text alignment

Tags: javascript, html-table, export-to-excel

I am using javascript to generate a large table (of around 15000 rows) and export it to excel. I am converting it into a blob and then exporting using the following code.

```
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) tableNode = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: tableNode.innerHTML}
    str = base64(format(template, ctx));
    var blob = b64toBlob(str, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.location = blobUrl;
  }
```

It is working fine. However, I am not able to vertically align the text in the excel sheet to the top. I have tried multiple plugins and could not find anything suitable. The table contains

- merged cells
- hyperlinks
- large amount of data
- text alignment

I require a solution which will generate the excel file quickly and will support all features

*Tried approaches:* 
 - SheetJS was slow since I iterated over the cells and added hyperlinks to a cell in each row.
 - Xlsx does not support hyperlinks.

Please let me know a suitable solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by simply adding css to the td `vertical-align: top` to the table.

Thanks :)